# Open PDF in new Tab/Window in IE via javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
 <button onmousedown="window.open('http://www.myurl.com/mypdf.pdf')">
                   Open PDF in new Tab
 </button>
```

I want to open a PDF in a new window/tab with the above code. In **IE** it does open the tab but not the PDF (viewer). Is this an IE bug or is there a workaround? I have to use javascript instead of `target="_blank`.

Comment: What is opened instead?

Comment: which version of IE you testing ?

Comment: a blank frame is opened. IE 11

Comment: It is a browser setting on IE on how to open up pdfs.